# Show fields with null ONLY in Swagger Response

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger-net

I am using Swagger-Net 8.43.* in .Net 4.8 Web Api

Is it possible to **show** null values in response body (not in Example value) **only** in Swagger UI without changing SerializerSettings for whole Api?

Now I have registered IgnoreNulls

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```

and not going to change it. But want to show ONLY in swagger

Comment: Not natively.  Why would you want to do this?  Swagger is meant to produce exactly what your API produces.

Comment: because some dummy consumers, when doesn't see some fileds, they are accepting it as breaking changes. Because of performance, I turned off null values api real response

Comment: Wouldn't you still have the problem though when they go to consume your API and the fields aren't there?  I'd think that if your example response includes the fields that you could clearly explain in the response description that fields will not be present if they are null.  You can also indicate in the Swagger docs that the field is nullable (ie- `nullable: true`).

Comment: defeats the purpose of swagger.... because now your swagger does not match your api